# Interest is theft or standalone prohibition

Tags: riba

Is lending money at interest forbidden because it is theft or is it not theft but forbidden as a standalone sin?

Comment: Why would it be theft? Theft is taking something without a person's knowledge or permission by way of stealth from a place of safekeeping. Interest is not theft.